# What should be ideal value of Filtered column in mysql explain clause?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, mysql-8.0, mysql-5.6

As per [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/explain-output.html#explain-output-columns)

> rows shows the estimated number of rows examined and rows × filtered /
> 100 shows the number of rows that will be joined with previous tables.

in my case i have executed one simple select query on mysql 5.6 and 8.o and find that filtered column result is different.

```
 Explain SELECT * FROM  test_source ts WHERE ts.host_id=2 and ts.eventsource_id in( 1,19) limit 1;
```

Mysql 8.o output
[image]

mysql 5.6
Filtered column showing 100.

which should be the ideal value of filtered to compare the query cost?

Comment: @Bill Karwin i haven't received proper answer. in my case same query filtered column result is at 5 and at 5.6 its 100. i just want to know which is better here. mysql 8.o is latest release so how and why filtering behavior changed . it is better if i get some link related with filteration working by mysql 8.o.

Comment: Did you see the link to the MySQL manual I added to my answer? I will include it here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/condition-filtering.html

Comment: Thanks.can you elaborate last line
[
Or, for a given query, using an optimizer hint: 
SELECT /*+ SET_VAR(optimizer_switch = 'condition_fanout_filter=off') */
]

Comment: That syntax disables condition filtering for a single query.

Comment: thanks. one more query, if i disable optimizer_switch at query level will it create performance overhead?

Comment: You'll have to test that. The answer could depend on many factors specific to your data and your environment.